# Unable to deploy Xamarin Froms iOS App it just keeps breaking on physical device

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

this is the first time I'm trying to write a request to you. Normaly I had could resolve most of the problems thanks to stackoverflow and others.

I developed an Xamarin.Forms App which runs on Android perfectly but when I try to deploy it to iOS (physical iPhone 8) it keeps breaking.

After searching for hours and trying diffrent things I hope someone can read out of the Code whats the matter...

I tried as well to set breakpoints in the appdelegate or first Page but after some seconds everthing breaks with this information:

```
2021-08-27 18:39:24.004 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[4330:1030659] Xamarin.iOS: Successfully received USB connection from the IDE on port 10000, fd: 6

2021-08-27 18:39:24.007 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[4330:1030659] Xamarin.iOS: Processing: 'start profiler: no'
2021-08-27 18:39:24.007 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[4330:1030624] Xamarin.iOS: Profiler not loaded (disabled)

Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/092BCD0C-2FC9-4F1B-A83E-29D87ACD245E/SHAPP.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
   
2021-08-27 18:39:24.334 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[4330:1030624] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'SHAPP' (culture: '')

2021-08-27 18:39:24.334 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[4330:1030624] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'SHAPP' (culture: '')


Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6FE32CF0-AE4D-41A2-BBBA-EAD56133AA7E/Documents/SHAPP.iOS.content/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
2021-08-27 18:39:24.404 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[4330:1030624] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'FFImageLoading' (culture: '')

2021-08-27 18:39:24.404 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[4330:1030624] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'FFImageLoading' (culture: '')

Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6FE32CF0-AE4D-41A2-BBBA-EAD56133AA7E/Documents/SHAPP.iOS.content/FFImageLoading.Platform.dll [External]
....
[0:] Failed to force load assembly /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6FE32CF0-AE4D-41A2-BBBA-EAD56133AA7E/Documents/SHAPP.iOS.content/Forms9Patch.dll. Type:Forms9Patch.PopupLayerEffect. Exception: 'You must call Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(); prior to using this property.'. Callstack: '  at Xamarin.Forms.Device.get_PlatformServices () [0x00007] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Device.cs:87 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Device.GetAssemblies () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Device.cs:245 
  at Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Initialize () [0x00021] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\DependencyService.cs:103 
  at Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get[T] (Xamarin.Forms.DependencyFetchTarget fetchTarget) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\DependencyService.cs:28 
  at Forms9Patch.Settings.ConfirmInitialization () [0x00008] in C:\Users\ben\Development\Xamarin\Forms9Patch\Forms9Patch\Forms9Patch\Models\Settings.cs:116 
  at Forms9Patch.PopupLayerEffect..cctor () [0x00000] in C:\Users\ben\Development\Xamarin\Forms9Patch\Forms9Patch\Forms9Patch\Effects\PopupLayerEffect.cs:19 '
...
[0:] An error occurred: 'Could not create an native instance of the type 'Airbnb.Lottie.LOTAnimationView': the native class hasn't been loaded.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.'. Callstack: '  at Foundation.NSObject.InitializeObject (System.Boolean alloced) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:247 
  at Foundation.NSObject..ctor (Foundation.NSObjectFlag x) [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:147 
  at UIKit.UIResponder..ctor (Foundation.NSObjectFlag t) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIResponder.g.cs:74 
  at UIKit.UIView..ctor (Foundation.NSObjectFlag t) [0x00000] in
```

...
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

```
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 
  at SHAPP.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\VisualCSharp\MyProjects\SHAPP\SHAPP.iOS\Main.cs:17 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/RuntimeMethodInfo.cs:395 '
Die App wurde beendet.
```

---

Thanks Jason and Saamer,

as you wrote i did try to fix that error prior to my request. But I could not find a way.
My AppDelegate looks like that:

```
    using Foundation;
using Lottie.Forms.Platforms.Ios;
using UIKit;

namespace SHAPP.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            Forms9Patch.iOS.Settings.Initialize(this);
            FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init();
            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();
           // ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure = false;
            LoadApplication(new App());

            //AnimationViewRenderer.Init();

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

So nothing to special, I did even try to set the old Lottie Init, but it did not help. As well I tryed to cancel all nuget Lottiefiles in iOS and to reinstall them, afterwards I cleaned the projects and restartet the build, same error.

Only working thing is to completly cancel Lottieusage.

The Lottie-XAML I use look's like that:

```
                 <lottie:AnimationView   
                    Animation="14525-plumbers.json"                    
                    AutoPlay="True"
                    RepeatCount="3"
                    RepeatMode="Restart"
                    CacheComposition="True"                   
                    HeightRequest="500"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    IsVisible="true"
                 />
```

If I comment it out everything works fine.
The LottieAnimationfile is in my RessourcesFolder (BundledRessource) as well as in the main folder.

[Folders iOS and LottieFiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCGoV.png)

Gentlement any ideas, what could be wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: there are some pretty clear error messages - have you acted on any of them?  ie, "Exception: 'You must call Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(); prior to using this property.'".

Answer (score 0):

As Jason mentioned, you need to add that line in the AppDelegate, as you can see in [this example](https://github.com/Baseflow/LottieXamarin/blob/develop/Samples/Forms/Example.Forms.iOS/AppDelegate.cs)

But you have another error too as you can read the error message at the end of the StackTrace you shared:

```
An error occurred: 'Could not create an native instance of the type 'Airbnb.Lottie.LOTAnimationView': the native class hasn't been loaded.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.'. Callstack: '  at Foundation.NSObject.InitializeObject (System.Boolean alloced) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:247 
  at Foundation.NSObject..ctor (Foundation.NSObjectFlag x) [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:147
```

What Lottie package are you using? Is it [this one](https://github.com/Baseflow/LottieXamarin)? Are you using the latest version?
You have to make sure that you add the iOS version of the Lottie package to the iOS project.